# How to get the dimensions of the equipements of a 3D model in forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I have a 3D model which is a NWD charged in forge viewer and I want to export for each equipement the dimensions (width, rayon, weight,..). In the [3D model in forge viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9aTs.png) I want for example export the rayon of the circle in a file and any meta data can be exported for that equipement.

Is there any extension or method to export the meta data of each equipement using forge viewer ?